# Show that there are numbers c and d such that F(A) = cTr(A^2) + d(Tr(A))^2,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratics, orthogonality, trace

Suppose F(A) is a quadratic function of a real symmetric matrix, A.  This means that there are numbers $f_{ijkl}$ so that F(A) = $\sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}a_{ij}a_{kl}$.

Suppose that $F(A) = F(QAQ^t)$ for every orthogonal matrix, Q.  Show that there are numbers c and d so that $F(A) = cTr(A^2) + d(Tr(A))^2$.  Here, Tr(A) is the trace of A.

Edited work:

Since A is symmetric, then we know that A is orthogonally diagonalizable, so that there's an orthogonal matrix Q such that $QAQ^t$ = D, where D is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of A on the main diagonal.

Using the assumption that F is invariant under *all* orthogonal similarity transformations, including (of course) the transformations that diagonalize A, I have that:

$$F(A) = F(QAQ^t)$$

$$= F(D)$$
$$=\sum_{i,j,k,l} f_{i,j,k,l}d_{ij}d_{kl}$$
$$=\sum_{i,k} f_{iikk}d_{ii}d_{kk}$$
$$= F(Q_1DQ_1^t)$$
$$= F(Q_2DQ_2^t)$$
$$= F(Q_3DQ_3^t)$$
$$....$$

$$=\sum_{i,k} f_{iikk}d_{ii}d_{kk},$$

where $Q_i$ is an orthogonal, permutation matrix, so that $Q_iDQ_i^t$ is *swapping the eigenvalues* on the diagonal, resulting in a permuted diagonal matrix, still with the eigenvalues of A on the main diagonal.

Now, the problem reduces to proving the equation for *diagonal* matrices.

As whacka stated in his answer below, considering only the permuted, diagonal matrices, then F defines a quadratic form in the variables $\lambda_i$, for $1\le i \le n$.

So, we have $$ F(\lambda_1, ... \lambda_n) = \sum_{i,k} f_{iikk}\lambda_i \lambda_k $$

$$ = \sum_{i=k} \alpha_i (\lambda_i)^2 + \sum_{i,k} \beta_{ik}\lambda_i \lambda_k $$

$$ = \sum_{i=k} \alpha_i (\lambda_i)^2 + \sum_i \sum_k \beta_{ik}\lambda_i \lambda_k$$

$$ ?? = \sum_{i=k} \alpha_i (\lambda_i)^2 + \beta_{ik} (\sum_i\ \lambda_i\sum_k  \lambda_k) $$

$$ = \alpha_i Tr(A^2) + \beta_{i,k}(Tr(A))^2$$

$$=F(A)$$

And, since F is invariant under any permutation of the eigenvalues on the diagonal, then this quadratic polynomial is *also* invariant; hence, the coefficients $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_{i,k}$ exist, are well-defined, and unique.

How is my proof?  I don't feel confident about the equality that I labeled (??).  But somehow, I have got to make that number, $\beta_{i,k}$ not dependent on the indices, in order to pull it outside of the summation, so that I can get my $(tr(A))^2$.

Any hints or suggestions are welcome and greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: There's still a lot more that can be deduced about $F$.  By choosing $Q$ to be a permutation matrix, you should be able to show that many of the values of $f_{ij}$ must be equal to one another.

Comment: Hi @ErickWong, I just read up a bit on permutation matrices on Wolfram; there are n! permutation matrices for an nxn matrix, with each matrix having exactly a single "1" in each row and column.  However, how -- or why -- should I choose such a matrix to be Q?  The orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes A may not necessarily consist of column vectors that are standard basis vectors, e.g., vectors $e_1$, $e_2$, ... $e_n$.  (Although the columns of Q should certainly be mutually orthogonal and of unit length.)

Comment: If I pick Q in the way you suggest, then I feel that I can no longer look at the simpler summation - F(D), a summation over two indices, i and k, instead of four indices, i,j,kl.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: The simplest example of a permutation matrix is one that swaps a single pair of entries.  Typically these types are all you ever need to consider (since the full permutation group is generated by all the swaps).  The goal at this stage is to extract more information about $F$ from the (very powerful) fact that it is invariant under ALL orthogonal transformations, not just the ones that diagonalize $A$.  Also, note that applying a permutation matrix to a *diagonal* matrix preserves diagonality.

Comment: I agree the diagonalizing matrix is still very useful for easily relating $\text{Tr}(A)$ and $\text{Tr}(A^2)$ to $\text{Tr}(D)$ and $\text{Tr}(D^2)$ without any tedious calculation.  But right now you need to deal with the large number of independent variables $f_{ij}$, which can be trimmed down to a very small number (you need to do this because the final result is expected to have only two parameters).

Comment: Hi @ErickWong, I played around with some orthogonal similarity transformations, using only the permutation matrices that you suggested.  Now I notice that these transformations simply swap the eigenvalues, resulting in another diagonal matrix with A's eigenvalues permuted (but still on the diagonal.)  All of these transformations, under the mapping of F, must agree, by assumption.  Am I a bit closer?  I should be able to equate some coefficients, but I'm not so sure how to do it.  I have posted my edited answer on my question post.  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @ErickWong, I have posted my latest answer, but I feel like I sort of pulled a fast one with the equality that I labeled (??).  I still somehow need to justify that step, if it's even correct -- although I feel it must be, since if not, then I'll never get my $(tr(A))^2$.  Feel free to comment on my updated work.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: A quadratic form looks like $\sum e_{ij}\lambda_i\lambda_j$. We can split this up into two parts, $\sum e_{ii}\lambda_i^2$ and $\sum_{i\ne j} e_{ij}\lambda_i\lambda_j$. And then the second we can split further up into $\sum_{i<j}c_{ij}\lambda_i\lambda_j$ and $\sum_{j<i}c_{ij}\lambda_i\lambda_j$. The latter may be written instead as $\sum_{i<j}c_{ji}\lambda_j\lambda_i$. But $\lambda_i\lambda_j=\lambda_i\lambda_j$, so we may collect terms and write $\sum_i c_{ii}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{i<j}(c_{ij}+c_{ji})\lambda_i\lambda_j$. Even simpler is $\sum_i a_i\lambda_i^2+\sum_{i<j}b_{ij}\lambda_i\lambda_j$.

Comment: I do believe you would be able to see what's going if you see past the summation symbols. For instance, $e_{11} \lambda_1 \lambda_1+e_{12}\lambda_1\lambda_2+e_{21}\lambda_2\lambda_1+e\lambda_2\lambda_2$ you would know can be written much more simply as $\square \lambda_1^2+\square\lambda_2^2+\square\lambda_1\lambda_2$. You would see it even quicker if we wrote, say, $axx+bxy+cyx+dyy$ - you would know a simpler form for this is $ax^2+by^2+cxy$. Try it for $n=3$ with variables $x,y,z$ and coefficients $a,b,c,\cdots$ and see if you can see how this generalizes to what I said in my above comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've shown it suffices to prove $\exists c,d\in\Bbb R$ s.t. $F(A)$ is of the form $c\,{\rm tr}(A^2)+d\,{\rm tr}(A)^2$ for all *diagonal* matrices $A$, as $F$ and ${\rm tr}$ are both ${\rm O}_n$-invariant (the action being conjugation).

One may identify diagonal $n\times n$ real matrices with $\Bbb R^n$. A quadratic function $F:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ must be of the form $F(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)=\sum_ia_i\lambda_i^2+\sum_{j<k} b_{jk}\lambda_j\lambda_k$. Two polynomials define the same function of $\Bbb R$ iff they are the same polynomial, two polynomials are identical iff their monomials have the same coefficients, and $F$ defines the same function for any permutation of its variables.

The key here is that $S_n$ acts transitively and $2$-transitively (in the language of group actions), so that we may permute all of the $a$ coefficients in front of the $\lambda_i^2$ terms, and permute any two $b$ coefficients in front of the $\lambda_i\lambda_j$ terms. If you are unfamiliar with the concept of a group action, you should still be able to take all this in stride I think.

Keeping in line with the language of group actions, the contragredient action of $S_n$ on functions is actually given by $(\sigma\cdot F)(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)=F(\lambda_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\cdots,\lambda_{\sigma^{-1}(n)})$ (the inverses are necessary for this to define a left action instead of a right action, and it has a sensible explanation in terms of graphs of functions). Explicitly writing out the polynomials, we have

$$\begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle \sum_i a_i\lambda_i^2+\sum_{j<k}b_{jk}\lambda_j\lambda_k & \displaystyle = \sum_i a_i\lambda_{\sigma^{-1}(i)}^2+\sum_{j<k}b_{jk}\lambda_{\sigma^{-1}(j)\sigma^{-1}(k)} \\ & \displaystyle = \sum_i a_{\sigma(i)}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{j<k}b_{\sigma(j)\sigma(k)}\lambda_j\lambda_k \end{array} $$

We must interpret $b_{\bullet\bullet}$ as symmetric to make sense of the above when $\sigma(j)>\sigma(k)$. Note the substitution of index that implicitly occurred. If we identify the coefficients of $\lambda_i^2$ above we get $a_i=a_{\sigma(i)}$ regardless of which $\sigma$ we picked, hence all $a$s are equal, and similarly equating coefficients of $\lambda_i\lambda_j$ yields $b_{jk}=b_{\sigma(j)\sigma(k)}$, hence all $b$s are equal: given any two pairs $j<k$ and $l<m$ there is a $\sigma\in S_n$ s.t. $\sigma(j)=l,\sigma(k)=m$ (this is what $2$-transitivity speaks to).

Now, given $F(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)=a\left(\sum_i\lambda_i^2\right)+b\left(\sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\lambda_j\right)$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb R$, can you conclude from this that it's of the form $F(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)=c\left(\sum_i\lambda_i^2\right)+d\left(\sum_j\lambda_j\right)^2$ for some $c,d\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: Hi @whacka, for the second term of the quadratic function, why do we sum over j<k?  And, why are we introducing a new matrix, B, and summing over its entries below the diagonal, j<k?  Thanks,

Comment: I've been studying your solution for the past hour, as well as reading the Wikipedia page on quadratic forms.  It's starting to make more sense now.  So, the problem reduces to showing that F defines a quadratic form, with the n eigenvalues as its *inputs*, for diagonal matrices.  Then, since F is invariant under any permutation of D, then all the quadratic polynomials gotten from F( some permutation of D) are equal.  Then it follows that the coefficients of the monomials must be equal.

Comment: I know I am not saying anything new, but ...do you think I have it correct, so far?  If so, my lingering confusion is, 1) why we only sum the second term for j<k, and 2)  other than saying that the coefficients must be equal, can we say what the coefficients are - explicitly?  Thanks for your time, @whacka.

Comment: Yes you have it right so far. (1) Nobody writes e.g. $xy+yx$ on paper in a commutative setting; we simply write $2xy$. Same idea with any number of variables; we have $\lambda_i\lambda_j=\lambda_j\lambda_i$ so there's no reason to include that monomial twice. (2) The numbers $a$ and $b$ can be anything in general, because $a(\cdots)+b(\cdots)$ is a quadratic form no matter what $a$ and $b$ are.

Comment: Hi @whacka, I actually just posted my work on the question post.  I feel I am very close, but need a bit more justification on the equality that I labeled (??).  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames It is not justified. Your $\beta_{ik}(\sum_i \lambda_i\sum_k\lambda_k)$ **doesn't even make sense**. Nor does $\alpha_i\,{\rm Tr}(A^2)$. The correct idea is that if all of the $b_{ij}$s are equal, you can simply use a single letter $b$ to denote the value, in which case $\sum_{i<j} b\lambda_i\lambda_j=b\sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\lambda_j$ by linearity.

Comment: oh, right!! we equate the coefficients!!  :-)

Comment: So, how do we get $(tr(A))^2$ from the sum over i<j, @whacka?  Thanks,

Comment: Read the very last line in my answer. First you'll want to go from the desired form $c(\cdots)+d(\cdots)^2$ to the known form $a(\cdots)+b(\cdots)$, and from there figure out how to reverse the process. What happens if you expand the $(\sum \lambda_i)^2$ that appears in the desired form?

Comment: Hi @whacka, so expanding out $(tr(A))^2$, as you suggested, and comparing it with your second term, I notice that $(tr(A))^2$ gives us an **extra** term, namely sum of $(\lambda_i)^2$, while the second term in the expansion matches your summation, summing over i<j, with coefficient = **2**, collecting terms as you had suggested.

Comment: But our quadratic function, F, does not have this extra term, so how can we squeeze out the $(tr(A))^2$ term?

Comment: A wild guess would be...some sort of...completing the square...

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're saying. If you mean $$c\left(\sum_i\lambda_i^2\right)+d\left(\sum_i\lambda_i\right)^2=\underbrace{ (c+d)}_a \left( \sum_i\lambda_i^2\right)+\underbrace{(2d)}_b \left(\sum_{j<k}\lambda_j\lambda_k\right)$$ then yes. Equating $a=c+d,b=2d$ and solving $d=b/2,c=a-b/2$ tells us that $$a\left(\sum_i\lambda_i\right)+b\left(\sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\lambda_j\right)=(a- \frac{1}{2}b)\left(\sum_i\lambda_i^2\right)+\frac{b}{2}\left(\sum_i\lambda_i \right)^2.$$

Comment: I finally, finally got it, @whacka, and I can finally leave the library and go to bed.  Thank you so, so, so much for your help and for your patience.  Oh, gosh, what a great learning experience.  I really appreciate it.  Have a great night!!  Thanks again!!